# Prevent nix build from querying cache.nixos.org

Tags: nix, nixos

when trying to build a derivation:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = "testdrive";
    version = "1.0.0";
    src = ./. ;
    phases = [
        "unpackPhase"  
        "buildPhase" 
        "installPhase"
    ];
    buildPhase = ''
        ${gcc}/bin/g++ a.cc -o a
    '';
    installPhase = ''
        mkdir -p $out/
        cp a $out/
    '';
}
```

nix always queries `https://cache.nixos.org` before the actual build. Since the dependencies was retrieved at first build, the subsequent query seems redundant and inefficient.

documentation around [nix build](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_command/build) command is a bit obscure. the behavior seems to relate to how nix handle the `src`.

how to disable the query?

Comment: You can set `allowSubstitutes = false` inside your derivation to turn it off from that end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nix build --option substitute false` will do the trick.

Note that the `nix` command is still in development as of writing.

Comment: What options are available for nix-shell? setting allowSubstitutes = false;  int the shell derivation will still make nix check for the dependencies

Comment: `nix-shell` also takes `--option` arguments. You can not affect its substitution behavior from within the expression. With flakes on the other hand, you can use the `nixConfig` attribute, but this is also still experimental and doesn't readily apply to `shell.nix`; you need to write a flake with a `devShells.<system>.default` for it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shorthand `--no-substitute` to pretty much any `nix-*` command.